# How to allow access to only one NTFS folder of already mounted partition for specific user?

Tags: fstab, ntfs-3g

I have two users: userA and userB. I have also NTFS formatted parition. Whole parition is only accessible to userA thanks to this in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda3 /home/userA/data ntfs-3g defaults,rw,nouser,uid=userA,umask=077,exec 0 0
```

. I want to allow ONE folder (for example /home/userA/data/movies) to be accessible for userB, but not whole drive. How can I do this?

If I allow all users in fstab, both users have access to whole drive, regardless if it is mounted in /home/userA/ folder. userB can simply do

```
ls /home/userA/data
```

even if he can't do

```
ls /home/userA
```

If I leave fstab as I have it set now and I use symlink, symlink respects permissions to folder it's linked to and userB won't be allowed to use this symlink.

I also tried to use remount option, but only thing it can change is ro/rw option, it can't change uid, guid or similar for ntfs partitions. I guess policy below (from man mount) applies to ntfs too:

> The -o remount may not be able to change mount parameters (all
>   ext2fs-specific parameters, except sb, are changeable with a remount,
>   for example, but you can't change gid or umask for the fatfs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the client machine is running Linux.

Linux has the ability to create multiple views of all or part of the same filesystem. You can use this to make only part of a filesystem accessible to a user (subject to further permission checks).

```
/dev/sda3 /home/userA/data ntfs-3g defaults,rw,nouser,uid=userA,umask=077,exec
/home/userA/data/subdir /home/userB/subdir bind
```

The command `mount --bind /home/userA/data/subdir /home/userB/subdir` sets up that second view.

If `/home/userA` is not accessible to user B then user B will not be able to access the NTFS partition through that view. However user B will be able to access the `subdir` directory through the view at `/home/userB/subdir`. Permissions still apply: some files under `subdir` may not accessible if their permissions exclude userB.

If you want to tweak permissions as well (to allow userB to access all files, or to grant read-only access only, etc.), you can use [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs). See [read only access to all files in a specific sub-folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49800/read-only-access-to-all-files-in-a-specific-sub-folder/49828#49828) and [Allow a user to read some other users' home directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91488/allow-a-user-to-read-some-other-users-home-directories/91522#91522) for example.

Comment: Nice, bindfs was what i needed

Answer (score 0):

NTFS-3g supports access control lists, ACLs. It's highlighted here on the [NTFS-3g website](http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/advanced-ntfs-3g.html). To interact with ACLs you use the command line tools `setfacl` & `getfacl`.

If this works with your particular mounted shares you should be able to use the `setfacl` command to allow userB access to this one particular folder.

```
$ setfacl -m user:userB:rwx /home/userA/data/movies
```

You may need to allow more than the above given it's a directory, the command above I've used for giving out just single file access.